# Early 2000s cartoon about humans fighting a war with some kind of alien species in space

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon, military-sf

I remember watching a cartoon (series?) in the late 90s early 2000s about humans fighting a war in space. They had tanks and artillery and mostly wore armor. I believe they were fighting some kind of (insectile?) alien species.

I had always thought that was a *Starship Troopers* cartoon, however I recently learned that there were only two *Starship Troopers* animations. One anime from the 80s and one CGI from the 90s. That's the right time frame, but what I remember was a western 2D animation with fairly bright colors. Nothing like the *Roughnecks: Starship Troopers Chronicles* series and more fluid looking and brighter than the anime.

Comment: Fairly bright colors... Do you remember anything about what they wore? Were there aliens in it?

Comment: @Arcanestomper - Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a movie or series?

Comment: Questor, the humans I think mostly wore armor. They were fighting aliens, and I think the aliens were insectile. That's why I thought it was starship troopers.

LogicDictates, I think it was a series, but at this point I'm not certain.

Comment: Exosquad? Not sure if the timing works...

Comment: @Shawn - Post it as an answer

Comment: @Valorum I'm not confident enough in it. Especially given the part about possibly insectile bad guys, which isn't a thing in Exosquad.

Comment: @Shawn - Sure, but OP has Starship Troopers all jumbled up in their memory. Everything else about it sounds right.

Comment: Annoyingly enough the concept art for starship troopers looks exactly like what I remember. Like this https://www.deviantart.com/filbarlow/art/Starship-troopers-Roughnecks-211215023. But that's not what the actual CGI show looked like.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly [Exosquad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exosquad) from 1993-1994?

Humans versus, not insectile aliens, but blue skinned artificial humans called Neosapians, with action on several planets in the solar system, plus space. The characters piloted a wide variety (because there was a toy line) of armored mini mecha called E-frames that were stuffed full of missiles and guns. The Neosapian frames could be considered vaguely insectoid with the haze of years...

Opening:

Comment: Hmm, that's closer than anything else I've found. I don't quite think it matches because I don't really remember mechs. But honestly I'm doubting my own memory at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Was it "[Stargate: Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Infinity)" (2002)?

> Stargate Infinity is set 30 years into the future and follows Gus
> Bonner and his team. Bonner's team was created after he was framed for
> a crime he did not commit. He escaped from Stargate Command (SGC)
> after the hostile alien race Tlak'kahn attacked the SGC to steal a
> mysterious alien chrysalis that was recently unearthed in Egypt.
> Together with his team, Gus escapes through the Stargate with the
> chrysalis. From that point forward they go visit planet to planet
> until they find the evidence to clear their names while learning about
> the unique cultures in the galaxy, so that they can one day return to
> Earth.

[image]

Comment: You've been on the site for long enough to know that Story-ID answers should be given some detail as to why you think it's the correct answer.

Comment: That's actually pretty close to the right timeframe and style of animation that I remember. It's not it though because I do remember it was more of a larger war than focused on small squad fights.

I am surprised there was a stargate animation. I had never heard of it before.

Comment: @Arcanestomper - It wasn't very good. You didn't miss much.